# Projecting a Texture Mask onto an existing 3D Mesh given the camera extrinsics

Tags: python, point-clouds, camera-calibration, open3d

Given an image mask, I want to project the pixels onto a mesh in respect to the position and orientation of the camera and convert these pixels into a pointcloud. I have the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters of the camera in respect to the world, and the location of the mesh in world coordinates. I know the mapping from world coordinates to camera image is as follow:

> imgpoint = Intrinsic * Extrinsic * worldpoint

So when I want to the opposite i do the inverse of the intrinsic and extrinsic matrices:

> worldpoint= Intrinsic^(-1) * Extrinsic^(-1) * imgpoint

However, the idea that I had was to obtain two points from one pixel, with different depth values, to obtain a line and then look for the closest intersection for the mesh I want with the line, but I do not know how to properly generate a point away from the original camera plane. How can I find this extra point and/or am I complicating this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The top equation below shows how to project a point *(x,y,z)* onto a pixel *(u,v)*;
The *extrinsic parameters* are the 3x3 rotation matrix *R* and translation **t**.
The *intrinsic parameters* are the *focal distances* *f_x, f_y* and
*principal point* *(c_x, c_y)*. The value *alpha* is the perspective foreshortening term that is divided out.

The bottom equation reverses the process by describing how to project
a ray from the *camera position* through through the pixel *(u,v)* out into the scene as the parameter alpha varies from 0 to infinity.

[image]

Now we have converted the problem into a [ray casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_casting) problem.
Find the intersection of the ray with your mesh which is a
standard computer graphics problem.